# SOAP Authheader

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I'm trying to add a header for authentication function but it seems not to be working when I test with a soap client below is my WSDL.My aim is to Implement a soap server in PHP with authentication function using a header that will contain a username and password.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://Jtl.co.ke/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2016/08/addressing" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2016/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2016/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2016/01/oasis-201601-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2016/09/mex" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="Service1" targetNamespace="http://Jtl.co.ke/">
   <wsdl:types>
      <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://Jtl.co.ke/">
         <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2016/07/CreateMBR" />
         <xs:element name="CreateMBRData">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2016/07/CreateMBR" minOccurs="0" name="composite" nillable="true" type="q1:CompositeType" />
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="CreateMBRDataResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element xmlns:q2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2016/07/CreateMBR" minOccurs="0" name="CreateMBRDataResult" nillable="true" type="q2:ReturnType" />
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>


 <xs:element name="AuthHeader">
  <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element xmlns:q3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2016/07/CreateMBR" minOccurs="0" name="CreateMBRDataResult" nillable="true" type="q3:ReturnType" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>


      </xs:schema>
      <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
         <xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType" />
         <xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI" />
         <xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary" />
         <xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean" />
         <xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte" />
         <xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime" />
         <xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal" />
         <xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double" />
         <xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float" />
         <xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int" />
         <xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long" />
         <xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName" />
         <xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short" />
         <xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
         <xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
         <xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong" />
         <xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
         <xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char" />
         <xs:simpleType name="char">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:int" />
         </xs:simpleType>
         <xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration" />
         <xs:simpleType name="duration">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
               <xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?" />
               <xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S" />
               <xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S" />
            </xs:restriction>
         </xs:simpleType>
         <xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid" />
         <xs:simpleType name="guid">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
               <xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}" />
            </xs:restriction>
         </xs:simpleType>
         <xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName" />
         <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID" />
         <xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF" />
      </xs:schema>
      <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2016/07/CreateMBR" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2016/07/CreateMBR">
         <xs:complexType name="CompositeType">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CUSTGRP" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EMAIL" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FNAME" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ORGNAME" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PAYMETHOD" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="STARTDATE" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="STATUS" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="STREET" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TAXCAT" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TELNUM" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>

         <xs:element name="CompositeType" nillable="true" type="tns:CompositeType" />
         <xs:complexType name="ReturnType">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MBR_NO" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MESSG" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="ReturnType" nillable="true" type="tns:ReturnType" />



      </xs:schema>



   </wsdl:types>



   <wsdl:message name="CreateMBRData_InputMessage">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateMBRData" />
   </wsdl:message>


   <wsdl:message name="CreateMBRData_OutputMessage">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateMBRDataResponse" />
   </wsdl:message>

   <message name="AuthHeader">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthHeader"/>
  </message>


   <wsdl:portType name="Jamii">
      <wsdl:operation name="CreateMBRData">
         <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://Jtl.co.ke/Jamii/CreateMBRData" message="tns:CreateMBRData_InputMessage" />
         <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://Jtl.co.ke/Jamii/CreateMBRDataResponse" message="tns:CreateMBRData_OutputMessage" />
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>


   <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Jamii" type="tns:Jamii">
      <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
      <wsdl:operation name="CreateMBRData">
         <soap:operation soapAction="http://Jtl.co.ke/Jamii/CreateMBRData" style="document" />
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
            <soap:header message="tns:AuthHeader" part="parameters" use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="Service1">
      <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_Jamii" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_Jamii">
         <soap:address location="" />
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

below is my PHP code for the Authentication header:

```
 function AuthHeader($Header)
 {
     if($Header->username == '' && $Header->password == '')
         $this->authenticated = true;    
 }
```

Comment: The soap client doesnt construct the header message